# Cakephp TinyMce

Tags: tinymce, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to get TinyMce setup with cakePhp, and the only thing that is loading is a textarea.  I am going off this article from The Bakery:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/galitul/2012/04/11/helper_tinymce_for_cakephp_2

I checked the spelling of my files and I have webroot/js/tiny_mce and View/Helper/TinymceHelper.php.  Do I need to add something else to my layout?

In my controller I have:

```
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Tinymce');
```

My View:

```
<?php echo $this->Tinymce->input('description', array(
     'label' => 'content'),
     array('language' => 'en'
         ),
     'bbcode'
     ); 
?>
```

Comment: Please improve your question, try to explain *what* isn't working. Describe what you tried to solve the problem (e.g. Are the TinyMce scripts included, are errors produced in your browsers console?). In its current state, your question is too wide to be properly answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't get the helper above, so I tried this plugin made by CakeDC that fixed the problem: https://github.com/CakeDC/TinyMCE

Once the file is extracted in the app/plugin directory, you'll simply want to add a helper in the controller that may look something similar to:

```
public $helpers = array('TinyMCE.TinyMCE');
```

In the /app/config/bootstrap.php file I added:

```
CakePlugin::load('TinyMCE');

...

Configure::write('TinyMCE.configs', array(
'advanced' => array(
    'mode' => 'textareas',
    'theme' => 'advanced',
    'plugins' => 'emotions,spellchecker,advhr,insertdatetime,preview',
    'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect',
    'theme_advanced_buttons2' => 'cut,copy,paste,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,|,code,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor',
    'theme_advanced_buttons3' => 'insertdate,inserttime,|,spellchecker,advhr,,removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions',
    'width' => '700',
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' => 'top',
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_align' => 'left',
    'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' => 'bottom',
    'theme_advanced_resizing' => 'true'
    )
  )
);
```

You can go to the TinyMCE website and configure the settings how you like.

Then once I have that configured and the helper added in my controller, I added:

```
$this->TinyMCE->editor('advanced');
```

That will turn the textareas on the form into a TinyMCE editor and load the settings from bootstrap.php (Note that you still have to create the textarea input on the view)

Comment: You may want to double check that you are loading in jquery, you are using cakephp 2.0+, and have PHP5.2+.  Also make sure you add "CakePlugin::load('TinyMCE');" in the bootstrap.php file.  I just edited my answer above.  If it still doesn't work, if you post a new question and show me your code I may be able to help.  Comment the link to your question below if you do create a question.

Comment: @Andrew ahm, did you use $this->Html->script('/TinyMCE/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', array(
    'inline' => false
)); as shown here : https://github.com/CakeDC/TinyMCE/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Setup.md ?

Answer (score 1):

If your CakePHP project is making user of Composer for dependency management and you want to include the CakeDC TincyMCE plugin (https://github.com/CakeDC/TinyMCE) you can use the following configuration in your composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "cakedc/tiny-mce": "1.2.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "app/Plugin/TinyMCE": ["cakedc/tiny-mce"]
        }
    }
}
```

I have specified a custom "installer-paths" in this case as my CakePHP application resides in /app but my composer.json is in the root. Without this the plugin would end up in /Plugin/TinyMCE rather than /app/Plugin/TinyMCE

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to know, is that currently, tutorial presented at:
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/galitul/2012/04/11/helper_tinymce_for_cakephp_2
is for TinyMCE 3.x. I didn't even start to rebuild given code to fit 4.x. What's more, tutorial makes use of advanced theme that is located inside TinyMCE 3.x package.

If you use CakePHP version 2.x and TinyMCE it should work pretty nice:

1. Download 3.x package from offical TinyMCE website at: http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php,
2. Extract jscripts/tiny_mce directory as explained in the tutorial (to app/webroot/js/)
3. Add: `public $helpers = array('Tinymce');` to every controller that needs TinyMCE.
4. Create TinymceHelper.php inside App/View/Helpers directory with code from tutorial
5. Inside add/edit or whatever is the name you gave for a file with tinyMCE field create the field like: `$this->Tinymce->input('ModelName.fieldname', $options = array(), $tinyoptions = array(), $preset = null);` 
   example:
    `echo $this->Tinymce->input('StaticPage.description', array('label' => 'Content'),array(), 'full');`

I hope this helps anybody :-)

Comment: Sorry but your method does not work, I followed your intructions exactly but my input fields load as normal with no TinyMCE helper!